# How to set Kendo Combo Box width as auto?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am trying with

```
var remoteDropDown = $("#ddl1").data("kendoComboBox");
    remoteDropDown.list.width("auto");
```

But it is not applying.

When kendo Combo Box is near to bottom of the page screen is shaking.

Can anyone help me how to fix this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [autoWidth](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox/configuration/autowidth) proeprty of the Combobox widget.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: [Here](https://dojo.telerik.com/EHuyAFiG) is a sample dojo where the width of the Kendo Combobox is updated based on the item with the longest text. If your scenario is somehow different please elaborate it.